# (edit) keep threads alive without changing main

Tags: c, pthreads

I would like to be able to start a pthread and that it will stay alive
Even if main() is done.

I don't have access to main().

the normal behavior is that if a thread is started and did't "join_thread" from main() it will be terminated when main done running.

in java, the default is that thread that was invoked will stay alive. Only when all threads are done the process will terminate. no explicit call to java "join_thread" is required.

Comment: Your description reads a bit contradictory IMO. On the one hand you say that you want `main` to implicitly join other threads it has started (i.e. wait for those threads to terminate), but then you also say that you _"want this thread to keep running after main reach to its last line"_. So which one is it?

Comment: the behavior I want is that when starting a thread it won't be terminated due to main reaching its end. I don't mind how to achieve that so either "join" or keep thread alive are good for me.

Comment: In that case you ought to rephrase your question to make it clearer what you want. Right now it can be intepreted as you wanting a return from `main` to always join all threads created by your program, without having to explicitly call `pthread_join`. But according to your comment, what you actually want is to exit your main thread while leaving the other threads running (which @Thrustmaster explained how to do in his answer).

Answer (score 2):

You could end your `main()` with a [`pthread_exit(..)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) instead of a `return 0`. This function call doesn't return. That way, your main thread would exit but your process wont finish.

The process would end when all threads are done, or `exit(..)` is called.

Comment: thanks, it's really great trick but can I don't want to change main()

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play with `atexit` function.

```
static pthread_t thread_ids[128];
static size_t    thread_count;
static pthread_mutex_t thread_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

static void join_all_threads()
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < thread_count; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(&thread_ids[i], NULL);
    }
    thread_count = 0;
}
```

Somewhere in the code:

```
...
atexit(join_all_threads);
...
```

In the thread code:

```
void *my_thread_fn(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex);
    thread_ids[thread_count++] = pthread_self();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex);

    ...
}
```

Edit: added on_exit

If you happen to have `on_exit` function, then it becomes simpler:

```
void my_thrad_join(int code, void *arg)
{
    pthread_join((pthread_t)arg);
}

void *my_thread_fn(void *arg)
{
    on_exit(my_thread_join, (void*)pthread_self());
}
```